# ${\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)}_p = {\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right)}_p$ if $x_j = y_j$?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a (real) manifold and let $(U , \varphi)$ and $(U , \psi)$ be two charts on $M$ with $\varphi = (x_1 , \ldots , x_n)$ and $\psi = (y_1 , \ldots , y_n)$. If $j \in \{1 , \ldots , n\}$, $p \in U$ and $x_j = y_j$, is ${\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)}_p = {\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right)}_p$ true? I think it should not be necessarily true, but I do not know how to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ depends not only on $x_j$ but the other variables as well.

Example.
Let's do change of variables from $(x_1,x_2)$ to $(y_1,y_2)$ like this:
$$
x_1 = y_1+y_2,
\\
x_2 = y_2,
$$
or in reverse
$$
y_1 = x_1-x_2,
\\
y_2 = x_2.
$$
So if your function is $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1$, which is the same function as $f(y_1,y_2) = y_1+y_2$,
then we get
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = 0,
\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_2} = 1.
$$
despite the fact that $x_2 = y_2$.